# How I can get the transcript of a YouTube Short?

Tags: youtube, accessibility

How can I get the transcript of a YouTube Short? I don't see any option to download it:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example with the YouTube Short https://www.youtube.com/shorts/XL9ns3BOFYs

Take the ID `XL9ns3BOFYs`, change the the YouTube Short URL to https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XL9ns3BOFYs, then click on "show transcript":

[image]